# 5 card poker hand contains 3 aces, conditional probability question

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, poker

Really struggling with this question and could use some guidance.

If a poker hand (five cards) is known to contain at least three aces, what is the probability that it contains all four aces?

I have been taking an approach using conditional probability to solve this and am coming up short. Thanks in advance

Comment: Edit the question to show us what you tried. It makes a better question to answer. To format the math, start with https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation and follow the links as needed.

Answer (score 2):

If there are at least three aces in the hand, either it contains exactly three aces or exactly four aces. Thus
$$P(4A|\ge3A)=\frac{P(4A)}{P(3A)+P(4A)}=\frac{\#(4A)}{\#(3A)+\#(4A)}=\frac{48}{\binom43\binom{48}2+48}=\frac{48}{4560}=\frac1{95}$$
where $\binom43\binom{48}2$ consists of choosing three aces from four and two cards from the 48 non-aces.